# ASP: Table buttons become unclickable: Buttons nested inside a table, inside a div

Tags: html, css, asp.net

So, I have a very simple ASP.Net page. It looks like this:

```
<head runat="server">
<style>
   *{ padding:0; margin:0; }
   table{ height:100%; width:100%; }
   input { background-color:black; width:100%; height:100%; }
</style>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Button ID="Button00" runat="server"  OnClick="Button_Click" /></td>
            <td><asp:Button ID="Button10" runat="server"  OnClick="Button_Click" /></td>
            <td><asp:Button ID="Button20" runat="server"  OnClick="Button_Click" /></td>
            <td><asp:Button ID="Button30" runat="server"  OnClick="Button_Click" /></td>
            <td><asp:Button ID="Button40" runat="server"  OnClick="Button_Click" /></td>
            <td><asp:Button ID="Button50" runat="server"  OnClick="Button_Click" /></td>
            <td><asp:Button ID="Button60" runat="server"  OnClick="Button_Click" /></td>
            <td><asp:Button ID="Button70" runat="server"  OnClick="Button_Click" /></td>
            <td><asp:Button ID="Button80" runat="server"  OnClick="Button_Click" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Button ID="Button01" runat="server"  OnClick="Button_Click" /></td>
            <td><asp:Button ID="Button11" runat="server"  OnClick="Button_Click" /></td>
  ...
```

This continues with 8 more table rows all looking just like the first one.
`Button_Click` performs an operation that I have already tested and it all works well. But I want the button grid to fill the height of the viewport, so when I added:

```
   div{ position:fixed;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        right:0;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;}
```

it fixed my formatting, but it made all of my buttons unclickable (they do, however, still display). I have looked around a bit, but can't find anything similar; I am looking for pure HTML or ASP.Net answers, as this page is being used for instructional purposes. I believe i have narrowed the issue down to the div position tag as shown in the two images the only difference is the presence of

```
position:fixed;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are there other elements after the div shown in the code sample?

Comment: no. only end tags.     </div></form></body></html>

Comment: OK. Because I tested with the same markup as yours and the buttons are "clickable" and the event handler is called. The problem occurs if another div is present as an overlay on top the one shown in your markup.

Comment: interesting, maybe its the compilers? asp.net controls turn into some ridiculously complicated code. are you in visual studios for c# 2015 debug mode?

Comment: I am with VS 2010, but I really doubt that it would make a difference. What do you mean when you say that your buttons are "unclickable"? A breakpoint in the event handler is not hit?

Comment: it is not hit, but more to the point, they no longer change the cursor on hover to the click cursor, they are not clickable in that they do not behave as a clickable element. no action occurs on clicking them and nothing indicates that they can be clicked.

Comment: Can you make a test with another browser? I don't have Edge, so I cannot say if it makes a difference.

Comment: it looks like you were right about an overlaying element, it is not there in my code, but upon inspecting the source code in firefox during debug, there is div tag called <div class="aspNetHidden"> above it. removing this element allows me to click buttons again, how can i tell the compiler to place it differently?

Comment: I have now checked, it happens in all browsers, i test in edge to make sure it will work in all browsers(edge is so limited afterall)

Comment: I posted an answer to address the problem of having another div in the HTML output.

Comment: I have looked around a bit, and i found that setting the z-index solves my problem, thank you, i would never have thought to look for overlaying div tags otherwise.

Comment: The z-index is one way. The other is to make sure that the divs are not superimposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you define the style to apply to all divs in the page, any other div after the table container will cover it and prevent the click. You can make sure that the style applies only to the table container by setting the `id` of the div:

```
<div id='div1'>
    <table>
        <tr>
        ...
        </tr>
    ...
    </table>
</div>
```

and by setting the style to apply to that specific div:

```
#div1
{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```